# "%%rax" in TinyHelloWorld.c

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

This code print "Hello World!" and exit without C library. ref.(Programmer's self-cultivation -- Link, load, and library)

I do not understand why there is **"%%" in front of "rax" in print()**, but **"%" in front of "rax" in exit()**. I have tried to add another "%" in front of "rax" in exit(), and I get the error message:

```
TinyHelloWorld.c:14: Error: bad register name `%%rbx'
TinyHelloWorld.c:15: Error: bad register name `%%rax'
```

WRITE has a system call number of 4 and EXIT is 1, I have no idea what is the difference about the use of "rax"?

```
char *str="Hello world!\n";

void print()
{
    asm("movq $13,%%rdx \n\t"
        "movq %0,%%rcx \n\t"
        "movq $0,%%rbx \n\t"
        "movq $4,%%rax \n\t"
        "int $0x80     \n\t"
        ::"r"(str):"edx","ecx","ebx");
}

void exit()
{
   asm("movq $42,%rbx   \n\t"
       "movq $1,%rax    \n\t"
       "int $0x80       \n\t");
}

void nomain()
{
   print();
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Here "%%" maybe an escape character for format string.

Comment: 2 unsafe things here: `"r"(str)` input constraint doesn't tell the compiler the pointed-to memory is also an input.  A dummy memory operand would be better.  Also, the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI doesn't work for 64-bit pointers, so this will fail if you build make a PIE executable.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Also inefficient: you can simply ask for inputs in the right registers, instead of using `mov` inside the asm, with `"a"(4), "d"(strlen(str)), ...`.  Let the compiler do everything but `syscall` or `int`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to docs and guides.

Answer (score 4):

The first block uses ["extended asm"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), the second ["basic asm"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html). In basic asm the single % prefix is used like in a standalone assembly source code: to determine a register. In extended asm the % prefix is used to identify one of the additional operators (InputOperands, OutputOperands, Clobbers, GotoLabels). To preserve the % prefix of the registers, you have to double it. This is called a [special format string](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Special-format-strings).

Informative: [How to Convert Basic asm to Extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended)